# How to download file in local machine which is selected in combo box?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing windows application, in which there are 3 buttons, 1 for browse, 1 for upload a file in sql server database and 1 for download the file from the database.

there is 1 combobox which shows the uploaded file of database, the user can select that file. I want to download that selected file.

Is it possible?
if yes then how?

Comment: "upload a file in sql server database" ? Sorry, but I'm not clear on exactly what you mean by this. Do you mean something like 'restore a database from a backup file'? Or...?

Comment: Are you using FILESTREAM in the database?

Answer (score 2):

You can FILESTREAM in the database for storing file or VARBINARY.
Here is a sample using VARBINARY.
You can improve it in many ways like using single connection object etc.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Add File";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    string[] sFilePath;
    sFilePath = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
    if (sFilePath.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(sFilePath);

}

private void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection thisConnection = new
          SqlConnection(@"YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
    thisConnection.Open();
    try
    {

        SqlCommand mySqlCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();


        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.SelectedItems)
        {

            string filepath = item.ToString();
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                continue;
            }
            string filename = new FileInfo(filepath).Name;
            byte[] rawData = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

            mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Files ( [fname],[file]) VALUES (@fname,@file)";
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
            mySqlCommand.Parameters["@fname"].Value = filename;
            mySqlCommand.Parameters["@file"].Value = rawData;

            mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        thisConnection.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        thisConnection.Close();
    }
    checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

    UpdateDropDown();
}

private void UpdateDropDown()
{

    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
    thisConnection.Open();

    string str = "SELECT id, fname FROM [Files]";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, thisConnection);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "uploadedfile");

    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["uploadedfile"].Rows)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(new { id = row[0], value = row[1] });
    }
    thisConnection.Close();
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "value";
    comboBox1.Update();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedid = 2;
    if (selectedid < 0)
    { return; }


    SaveFileDialog savefileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    savefileDialog1.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = false;
    savefileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    savefileDialog1.Title = "Save file as...";

    DialogResult result = savefileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (result != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    string filename = savefileDialog1.FileName;

    SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
    thisConnection.Open();

    string str = "SELECT [file], fname FROM [Files] where id =" + selectedid;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, thisConnection);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "uploadedfile");

    if (ds.Tables["uploadedfile"].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        byte[] bb = (byte[])ds.Tables["uploadedfile"].Rows[0]["file"];
        Save(filename, bb);
    }

    thisConnection.Close();


}
private void Save(string file, byte[] data)
{
    // save file 
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDropDown();
}
```